# plot_confusion_matrix without estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to use plot_confusion_matrix,

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_true = [1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [1, 1, 0, 0]

confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

Now, while using the followings; using 'classes' or without 'classes'

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=[0,1], title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
```

or

```
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
```

I expect to get similar output like this except the numbers inside,

[image]

Plotting simple diagram, it should not require the estimator.

Using mlxtend.plotting,

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

binary1 = np.array([[4, 1],
                   [1, 2]])

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=binary1)
plt.show()
```

It provides same output.

Based on [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html)

it requires a classifier,

```
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(classifier, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=class_names,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize=normalize)
```

**Can I plot it without a classifier?**

Comment: Can I plot it without a classifier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`plot_confusion_matrix` expects a trained classifier. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py#L119), what it does is perform the prediction to generate `y_pred` for you:

```
y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight,
                          labels=labels, normalize=normalize)
```

So in order to plot the confusion matrix without specifying a *classifier*, you'll have to go with some other tool, or do it yourself.
A simple option is to use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
f = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have to use pandas and seaborn to achieve it. Can I use tools from scikit-learn?

I see here, it used without a [classifier], (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40067/confusion-matrix-three-classes-python)

Comment: No @RakibulHassan .  In the link a custom function is being used. Why not just define it wourself?

Comment: Thank you. I thought it looked similar, can we not use ConfusionMatrixDisplay?

Answer (score 6):

I am a bit late here, but I thought other people might benefit from my answer.

As others have mentioned using `plot_confusion_matrix` is not an option without the classifier but it is still possible to use sklearn to obtain a similar-looking confusion matrix without the classifier. The function below does exactly this.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

def confusion_ma(y_true, y_pred, class_names):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, normalize='true')
    disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=class_names)
    disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    return plt.show()
```

The `confusion_matrix` function returns a simple ndarry matrix. By passing this together with labels of the predictions to the `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` function a similar looking matrix is obtained. In the definition I've added the `class_names` to be displayed instead of 0 and 1, chosen to normalize the output and specified a colormap - change accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Actually, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since plot_confusion_matrix require the argument 'estimator' not to be None, the answer is: no, you can't. But you can plot your confusion matrix in other ways, for example see this answer: [How can I plot a confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following "identity classifier" in a Jupyter notebook running the conda_python3 kernel in Amazon SageMaker. The reason is that SageMaker's transformation job  is async and so does not allow the classifier to be used in the parameters of `plot_confusion_matrix`, `y_pred` has to be calculated *before* calling the function.

```
IC = type('IdentityClassifier', (), {"predict": lambda i : i, "_estimator_type": "classifier"})
plot_confusion_matrix(IC, y_pred, y_test, normalize='true', values_format='.2%');
```

So while `plot_confusion_matrix` indeed expects an estimator, you'll not necessarily have to use another tool IMO, if this solution fits your use case.

[simplified POC from the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCPsI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of using a customized classifier; you can build any custom classifier and pass it to the plot_confusion matrix as a class:

```
class MyModelPredict(object):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self._estimator_type = 'classifier'
        
    def predict(self, X):
        return your_custom_prediction

model = MyModelPredict()
plot_confusion_matrix(model, X, y_true)
```